# mysql join, group concat or group by

Tags: mysql, sql, foreach, pivot

I have a table of `users`, `inductions`, and `user_inductions`.

- The `users` table has the `id` and `name`,
- the `inductions` table has `id` and `name`, and
- the `user_inductions` had `id`, `user_id` and `induction_id`.

I want to return a list of all inductions and people who have done them. This I have done however as I wish to create a table like below. I'm not sure how to edit the query, so I get the information back as I wish.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| name    | tennis | cricket | rugby | squash | football | Table tennis |   etc    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Bob     |   0    |   1     |   0   |    1   |    1     |     0        |          |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| paul    |   1    |   1     |   1   |    1   |    0     |     0        |          |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to loop through the data so I get the list of inductions at the top and then each user going down with 1 if they have been inducted on that subject and 0 if not. I had several queries but they only return either all users with only the inductions they've done or the inductions and those who've done them.

eg:

```
SELECT CONCAT(  `f_name` ,  ' ',  `l_name` ) AS user, GROUP_CONCAT( pmainductions.name
ORDER BY pmainductions.id ) AS induction
FROM users
LEFT JOIN pmainduction_user ON users.id = pmainduction_user.user_id
LEFT JOIN pmainductions ON pmainductions.id = pmainduction_user.pmainduction_id
GROUP BY users.id
```

this produces

```
bob | cricket,squash,football

paul| tennis,cricket,rugby,squash
```

any help would be appreciated. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(  `f_name` ,  ' ',  `l_name` ) AS user, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN pmainductions.name = 'tennis' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'tennis',
  MAX(CASE WHEN pmainductions.name = 'cricket' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'cricket',
  MAX(CASE WHEN pmainductions.name = 'rugby' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'rugby',
  ...
FROM users
LEFT JOIN pmainduction_user ON users.id         = pmainduction_user.user_id
LEFT JOIN pmainductions     ON pmainductions.id = pmainduction_user.pmainduction_id
GROUP BY users.id;
```

If you have unknown number of inductions for each users, and you want to do this dynamically, you can do this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(p.Name = ''',
      p.Name, ''', 1, 0)) AS ', '''',   p.Name , '''')
  ) INTO @sql
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_inductions up ON u.id = up.user_id
LEFT JOIN inductions      p ON p.id = up.induction_id;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT u.name AS user,' ,
                  @sql, ' FROM users u ',
                  ' LEFT JOIN user_inductions up ',
                  ' ON u.id = up.user_id',
                  ' LEFT JOIN inductions      p     ',
                  ' ON p.id = up.induction_id ',
                  ' GROUP BY u.id');
SELECT @sql;

prepare stmt 
FROM @sql;

execute stmt;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4519f/2)

This will give you something like:

```
| USER | TENNIS | CRICKET | RUGBY | SQUASH | FOOTBALL | TABLE TENNIS | TWO WORDS |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  bob |      1 |       1 |     1 |      1 |        1 |            0 |         0 |
| paul |      1 |       1 |     1 |      1 |        1 |            1 |         1 |
```

Comment: Hi thanks this worked except that when i add an activity that has two word eg: table tennis it returns an error. ( You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'skills,SUM(IF(p.Name = 'Headway', 1, 0)) AS Headway,SUM(IF(p.Name = 'Assessment'' at line 1: prepare stmt FROM @sql ) and also here you have counted the number of times the user has done it but i just want to have 1 attended and 0 if they have not. any help

Comment: @user1740151 - Yes, sorry I missed that. Just surround the alias name with two more quotes. See my updated answer.